# Scanner restarting in Java

Tags: java

My task is to read a text file in chunks of 64 characters, and use 2 different processes called Substitution and Column Transposition to encrypt it. Then, I have to decrypt it and write it out to another file.

I have written and tested out both processes of encrypting and decrypting and it worked wonderfully. But then I tried to loop the processes in case more than 64 characters were in the input file.

As a test case, I tried a 128 character input file. Unfortunately, the result only gives me the first 64 characters twice. I've tracked the scanner position and it goes beyond 64, but the characters read start back from 0. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```js
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  
  //Declare variables
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  String inputFileName = null;
  File inputFile = null;
  Scanner in = null;
  
  do
  {
   //Check if there are enough arguments
   try
   {
    inputFileName = args[1];
   }
   catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException exception)
   {
    System.out.println("Not enough arguments.");
    System.exit(1);
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
    System.out.println("There was an error. Please try again.");
    System.exit(1);
   }
   
   //Check if Input File is valid
   try
   {
    inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
    in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    outputFile = new File(outputFileName);
    out = new Scanner(outputFile);
   }
   catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
   {
    System.out.println("Could not find input file.");
    System.exit(1);
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
    System.out.println("There was an error. Please try again.");
    System.exit(1);
   }
  } while (outputFileName != null && !inputFile.exists());

  
  //Encryption

  //Prepare patterns
  String subPattern = CreateSubstitutionPattern(hash);
  int[] transPattern = CreateTranspositionPattern(hash);
  
  //Apply patterns
  String textContent = "";
  String applySub = "";
  String applyTrans = "";
  do
  {
   textContent = Read64Chars(in);
   applySub = applySub + ApplySubstitutionPattern(textContent, subPattern);
   applyTrans = applyTrans + ApplyTranspositionPattern(applySub, transPattern);
  } while (in.hasNext());
  
  //Decryption

  String encryptContent = "";
  Scanner encrypt = new Scanner(applyTrans);
  String removeTrans = "";
  String removeSub = "";
  do
  {
   encryptContent = Read64Chars(encrypt);
   System.out.println(applyTrans);
   removeTrans = removeTrans + RemoveTranspositionPattern(encryptContent, transPattern);
   removeSub = removeSub + RemoveSubstitutionPattern(removeTrans, subPattern);
  } while (encrypt.hasNext());
  
  console.close();
  in.close();
  encrypt.close();
  System.out.println(removeSub); //For temporary testing
  }

public static String Read64Chars (Scanner in)
 {
  String textContent = "";
  in.useDelimiter("");
  for (int x=0; x<64; x++)
  {
   if (in.hasNext())
   {
    textContent = textContent + in.next().charAt(0);
   }
  }
  return textContent;
 }
```

Do note that I have more variables to fill in args[0] and args[2] but I removed them for simplicity.

I would like to know if it is true that once a scanner reads a portion of it's input, it "consumes" it, and that portion gets removed. Does the scanner reset itself when declared again through a method? For example, does the declaration only point to the input source of the original scanner, or the actual scanner with its current properties?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You probably don't want to use scanner, since you're just reading a character at a time and not searching for tokens in the input.

Comment: Bad usage of Scanner. You should have first read whole file into a string. In Read64Chars you are not ensuring that the code reads next 64 characters. That is why it keeps on reading first 64 characters.

Comment: Adding to my earlier comment, your use of scanner might actually affect the correctness of your program, not just reduce its efficiency.  Scanner works with tokens, which are not guaranteed to fit into your 64 character boundary (a token such as a word might run from 62 characters to 75 characters in your input, for example, and so your reading routine would read more than 64 characters). I'd suggest using FileReader and FileWriter and reading a character-at-a-time.

Answer (score 0):

`encrypt` is a diffrent `Scanner` from `in`, which you advance by 64 characters when you first call `Read64Chars`. So, `encrypt` starts at the first character when you call `Read64Chars(encrypt)`. It seems like you want to use the same Scanner both times.

Also, in the future please name your functions starting with a lowercase letter. I felt dirty typing that... :)

Answer (score 0):

A proper solution to get the whole encrypted text would be a code like this

```
public static String encryptedTextFile (Scanner in)
{
    //ArrayList<String> stringBlocksOf64Chars = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder encryptedTxt = new StringBuilder();
    String currentTxt = "";
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = currentTxt + in.nextLine();
        currentTxt = "";
        int i = 0;
        for( ; i < line.length()/64 ; i++){
            currentTxt = line.substring(i * 64, (i+1)*64);
            //TODO - encrypt the text before adding it to the list
            encryptedTxt.append(currentTxt);//encryptedTxt.append(encrypt(currentTxt));
        }
        currentTxt = line.substring(i * 64, line.length());
    }
    encryptedTxt.append(currentTxt);
    /*for(String str : stringBlocksOf64Chars)
        System.out.println(str);*/
    return encryptedTxt.toString();
}
```

Your loop `for (int x=0; x<64; x++)` makes sure that you read only first 64 characters always and not the complete file. To get around that you should actually read whole file line by line.

The above code block follows this idea.

Steps to break down the logic.

1. Read the file line by line using scanner.
2. Break each line into chunks of 64 characters and encrypt the block 64 characters at a time
3. Generate encrypted text adding the encrypted 64 characters.

Whatever you do first break down the logic/steps you want to use in your code to make it simpler to understand or code.
Break the lines into 64 characters